# Restore intermediate checkpoint files of Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Tensorflow version =1.8.0

I am trying to restore my model using one of the intermediate checkpoint files in Tensorflow. By default Tensorflow will take the last saved checkpoint file. 
For example, the folder contains files like:

checkpoint
model-56000.index  model-56000.data-00000-of-00001  model-56000.meta                 model-57000.index  model-57000.data-00000-of-00001  model-57000.meta

By default, Tensorflow loads the last 57K checkpoint, but for reasons, I want to load the weights for the 56K checkpoint. 
Following is my code for restoring the model:

```
def load_G(self, checkpoint_dir):
    print(" [*] Reading checkpoints of G...")
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        ckpt_name = os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        self.saver_gen.restore(self.sess, os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, ckpt_name))
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

From Tensorflow's page, I read that for tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(), I can specify tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir, latest_filename=None). But I am not able to figure, what should I write for latest_filename. I tried writing latest_filename = model-56000
But that did not load the model.

I also tried writing latest_filename = model-56000.meta. That also did not work.

So, what is the correct way to load some intermediate checkpoint files in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,so a hack is to modify the *checkpoint* protobuf file and change the first line of that file from: *model_checkpoint_path: "model-57000"* to *model_checkpoint_path: "model-56000"* ad now it loads the 56K checkpoint.
Looking for some better ways to do this.

Answer (score -2):

The ckpt file name will be `model-56000.ckpt`

`model-56000.meta` points to the meta information of the ckpt

`model-56000` is file name for either ckpt, data files, or meta files

Comment: So, I wrote                                                                 
    tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir, latest_filename='model-56000.ckpt'). But still the IF condition is not getting True. Am I missing any point ?